# Revealing input type="password"

Tags: jquery, passwords

I'm trying to make a button to reveal the password written on the input.
My poor JS skills tell me that I can achieve it by doing something like this:

I tried this:

```
$('#passReveal').on('click', function(){
    $( "#input-show" ).attr('type', 'text');
    if ($( "#input-show" ).attr('type', 'text')){
        $( "#input-show" ).attr('type', 'password');
    }
});
```

But doesn't work.

I think this one is the closest, but I have a bug: you must click twice the button to make it work the first time, why is that?

```
$('#passReveal').on('click', function(){
    $( "#input-show" ).attr('type', 'text');
    $( "#input-show" ).toggleClass('passRevealed');
    if ($( "#input-show" ).hasClass('passRevealed')){  
        $( "#input-show" ).attr('type', 'password');        
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tepLkc7u/2/

I hope you understand my bad english, im learning :)

Comment: Your logic is the other way around.  You're using `.attr('type', 'passowrd')` when it should be `.attr('type', 'text')`

Answer (score 6):

You can't reliably change the `type` of an `input`, cross-browser.

What you can do instead is put two inputs next to each other and choose which one to show:

```js
$('#passReveal').on('click', function() {
  var show = $("#input-show"),
      pass = $("#input-pass"),
      showing = show.is(":visible"),
      from = showing ? show : pass,
      to = showing ? pass : show;
  from.hide();
  to.val(from.val()).show();
  $(this).text(showing ? "Reveal" : "Hide");
});
```

```html
<input type="password" id="input-pass" placeholder="Password">
<input type="text" id="input-show" placeholder="Password" style="display: none">
<button id="passReveal">Reveal</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Having `$(this).text('Reveal')` in the *then* block and `$(this).text('Hide')` in the *else* block would make this *perfect*.

Comment: @PeterKA: Ah, good point. :-) I also don't like the repeated code, but each time I tried to improve it, it got *worse* rather than better. I think I improved it in the end, though.

Answer (score 0):

What you were doing is toggling the class and then setting the input type to password if it had the class.

So, since it had the class the first time(it was toggled in), it would make the input type back to a password.

The second time, it would not because the input no longer had the class.

Nevertheless, to make it work the first time try

```js
$('#passReveal').on('click', function() {
  $("#input-show").attr('type', 'text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="input-show" placeholder="Password">
<button id="passReveal">Reveal</button>
```

**Update**

If you wish to achieve **IE-Compatibility** beware of changing the `type` attribute dynamically. Rather, follow the approach of using two seperate inputs like in @T.J. Crowders answer.

See [Changing <input> type using jQuery with cross browser support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881874/changing-input-type-using-jquery-with-cross-browser-support) and notes about *cross-browser consistency* in [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: You can't reliably change the `type`, cross-browser, of an existing `input`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, dont say *cross-browser*. This is about IE compatibility(rolling eyes). Thanks for the good answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881874/changing-input-type-using-jquery-with-cross-browser-support